# Access FairCom DB without using drivers provided by FairCom

Tags: jdbc, ctree, faircom

I m trying to create an application that requires access to FairCom data base running as part of another application.

Is there a way to query the data base without using the JDBC driver provided by FairCom.

Basically without getting any licenses, I want to be able to re distribute my application.